# how to bind DataTable to legend in mschart

Tags: c#, excel, mschart, legend

I use excel to paint a pic as follow:
**[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNMKy.png]**

please pay attention to the area hightlight in red

my question is:
how to bind the datatable to legend in mschart? 
so , except the legend color, also people can see the detail data from the legend.

or, you guys can tell is it feasible to bind in mschart? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is nothing in the API that allows you to simply "bind" your DataTable to a legend.

But you should still be able to manage something like that with some code:

```
var l = chart1.Legends[0];
l.LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Table;
l.TableStyle = LegendTableStyle.Tall;
l.BorderColor = Color.OrangeRed;
l.Docking = Docking.Bottom;
l.LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Table;
l.HeaderSeparator = LegendSeparatorStyle.DashLine;
l.HeaderSeparatorColor = Color.Red;

var firstColumn = new LegendCellColumn();
l.ColumnType = LegendCellColumnType.SeriesSymbol;
l.CellColumns.Add(firstColumn);

var secondColumn = new LegendCellColumn();
l.ColumnType = LegendCellColumnType.Text;
secondColumn.Text = "#SER";
l.CellColumns.Add(secondColumn);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    var column = new LegendCellColumn();
    column.ColumnType = LegendCellColumnType.Text;
    column.HeaderText = row["x"].ToString();
    column.Text = "#VALY";
    l.CellColumns.Add(column);
}
```

However, my suggestion would be to include the data in a separate control, rather than as part of the chart itself.  It would be much easier to work with if you kept it in one of the .net controls that's meant for tabular data, whether you're in winforms or webforms.

Comment: Do you have an idea why the string #VALY not replaced when i render the chart? it just stay #VALY.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am also getting same issue. string #VALY not replaced when i render the chart, Please help us

Comment: @RajeshPathakoti Ask a new question.